# Select SQL table data

Tags: sql, select

[image]

I have a table as shown in image. Here user 'A' has no outtime where Id=2. If I select UserId,Name,MIN(inTime) and MAX(outtime) from MyTable ,then i will get First InTime and Last OutTime . Instead of selecting like that, I want to set User 'A' last outtime as null. How is it possible?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `SQL Server`:

```
select *
from(select name, userid, dateatt 
     from table 
     group by name, userid, dateatt)t
cross apply(select top 1 intime from table
            where userid=t.userid and dateatt=t.dateatt order by id)i
cross apply(select top 1 outtime from table 
            where userid=t.userid and dateatt=t.dateatt order by id desc)o
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, MAX and MIN do not include NULL when evaluating data.

See the below query I have modified for you taken from article [here](http://www.bradleyschacht.com/select-null-as-max-or-min-in-sql-query/).

> We will use COALESCE to replace any NULL EndDate with a date that is in the future that will not be coming up in our data anywhere, December 31, 2099 seems like a reasonable date for this.  Next we take the MAX of the dates, which if NULL will evaluate as 12/31/2099 and be greater than any other date in our table.  Wrap that in a CASE statement to replace the date 12/31/2099 back to NULL and group our data by StoreID.
>
> `SELECT
>   Name,
>   CASE WHEN MAX(COALESCE(outtime, ’12/31/2099′)) = ’12/31/2099′ THEN NULL ELSE MAX(outtime) END AS outtime
>   FROM WorkSchedule
>   GROUP BY Name`